# Entity is not deleted on a many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to delete the SentGroupJoinRequest record
[record of userId and GroupJoinRequestId](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQHAC.png)

Which is created by the relationship between the `User` entity and the `SentGroupJoinRequests` field and the Group by the `JoinRequests` field, but when the properties of each entity are accessed and deleted, they are not deleted from the table.
Here's the method:

```
public async Task<ServiceResponse<string>> AcceptJoinRequest(int groupId, string memberId)
        {
            var serviceResponse = new ServiceResponse<string>();
            try
            {
                var group = await _context.Groups.FindAsync(groupId) ?? throw new Exception("Group not found.");

                if (group.OwnerId != _http.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue("Id"))
                {
                    throw new Exception("You are not group owner.");
                }
                var userRequest = await _context.Users.FindAsync(memberId) ?? throw new Exception("User not found.");
                if (group.Followers.Contains(userRequest))
                {
                    throw new Exception("User already in a group.");
                }
                group.Followers.Add(userRequest);
                userRequest.Groups.Add(group);
                userRequest.SentGroupJoinRequests.Remove(group);
                
                group.JoinRequests.Remove(userRequest);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                serviceResponse.Message = "You have approved the application.";
                serviceResponse.Success = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                serviceResponse.Success = false;
                serviceResponse.Message = ex.Message;
            }
            return serviceResponse;
        }
```

`User` Entity:

```
namespace SocialNetwork.Entities
{
    public class User
    {
        public string Id { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Surname { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public List<Group> Groups { get; set; } = [];
        public List<Group> SentGroupJoinRequests { get; set; } = [];
    }
}
```

`Group` Entity:

```
namespace SocialNetwork.Entities
{
    public class Group
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string OwnerId { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public List<Post> Posts { get; set; } = [];
        public List<User> Followers { get; set; } = [];
        public List<User> JoinRequests { get; set; } = [];
        public bool IsClosed { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Database setup:

```
namespace SocialNetwork.Data
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MetaData> MetaDatas { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasMany(u => u.Groups)
                .WithMany(f => f.Followers)
                .UsingEntity(j => j.ToTable("UserGroups"));

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasMany(u => u.SentGroupJoinRequests)
                .WithMany(j => j.JoinRequests)
                .UsingEntity(j => j.ToTable("UserJoinRequests"));
        }
    }
}
```

Why is the field not being deleted in the UserJoinRequests table, and how can I solve it?

A record in the database is not deleted, even if you delete two properties from different entities separately

Comment: Are there constraints on the table? If so, then deleting from the table will not be allowed in sql.

Comment: You have to get the groups and users by `Where` + `Include`. The collections you want to remove from must be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above, "cascade" deletion happens when you include "nested" object when first loading the data or calling the nested objects when doing the deletion.

Refer to this link for cascade delete
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete

```
using var context = new BlogsContext();

var blog = context.Blogs.OrderBy(e => e.Name).Include(e => e.Posts).First();

context.Remove(blog);

context.SaveChanges();
```

In this code you have to call the nested objects if you havent already when loading them, for example, to a list.

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blogs = context.Blogs
        .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
        .Include(blog => blog.Owner)
        .ToList();
}
```

Now, when selecting an object from said list and removing it, then you dont have to call all the "nested" objects again.

Refer to this link for "eager loading".
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager

You'll notice too if you debug, if you do not eager load then your variable will have its "nested" objects returned null.

Then just make sure you save your changes of course.

Comment: No problem, I work with EF core daily. Just trying to help out the community with that I’ve learned.